# PINCODE LOGIN PAGE

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

Im stuck with a project. This is strictly for a company internal employee login page. Not public! For those that might question the security of this form. Although, I am open to hashing the pincode password (SHA-1).

I've setup the code on my jsfiddle     [PINCODE LOGIN](https://jsfiddle.net/cptcrunchy/ezs7n4o8/16/)

```
<body onLoad="emptyCode()" class="hold-transaction login-page">
    <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="login-box">
<div class="login-logo">
  <a href="login.php"><b>PINCODE LOGIN</b></a>
  <p class="login-box-msg">Employee Sign-in</p>
</div>
<!-- /.login-logo -->
<div class="login-box-body">
  <!--<form action="" method="post">-->
  <div class="main_panel">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="4" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter PIN...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" >X</button>
            </span>
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->

      <table id="keypad" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td onclick="addCode('1');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>1</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td onclick="addCode('2');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>2</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td onclick="addCode('3');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>3</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td onclick="addCode('4');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>4</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td onclick="addCode('5');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>5</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td onclick="addCode('6');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>6</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td onclick="addCode('7');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>7</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td onclick="addCode('8');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>8</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td onclick="addCode('9');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>9</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td onclick="addCode('0');">
              <div class="button raised clickable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                <div class="anim"></div><span>0</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <p id="message">ACCESSIGN...</p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--</form>-->
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body -->
    </div>
  <!-- /.login-box --> 
</body>
```

My goal for this is:

1. Allow employees to login using a 4 digit pincode and verify
   against DB credentials
2. BONUS: Hash password in DB

Not sure if i would need a function such as " if(isset($_POST['code'])) {", as a separate file.

Comment: I wasn't sure where the function was suppose to go to verify the data against the DB credentials. In the javascript? In a separate php file?

Comment: most hacks are done by employees

Answer (score 1):

At first, you close the form tag at the end of the form, wich means nearly your whole page is posted back to your server. You can minify this:

```
<form action="secret.php" method="post">
<input name="code">
</form>
```

Now it is posted to the "secret.php" specified in the action tag.
This would look like this:

```
Secret.php:
<?php
if(isset($_POST["code"])){
if($_POST["code"]=="5473")){
echo "successfully logged in...";
$_SESSION["logged"]=true;
}else{
echo " wrong code";
}
}else{
echo "404: this is not accessible for you";
}
?>
```

This checks if the code is posted and if its 5473. if its correct, it sets a session wich helps you identifying the user.
Simply do:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["logged"])){
echo " logged in user...";
}else{
echo "not for you.please log in";
die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I'm not sure where to add this code. I hava a hidden PHP file that can perform the validation

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer

Comment: Oh i see. You already implemented it in js. I rewrite it , so that it deals with the necessary php parts

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code. This function seems to work great!

```
function loginEmployee() {
global $connection;
$pincode = $_POST["code"];

if(isset($_POST["code"])){
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_pin = '$pincode'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
echo "<p class='alert-successs'>successfully logged in...</p>";
header("Location: ../repairs.php");
die();
$_SESSION["logged"]=true;
}else{
header("Location: ../login_fail.php");
die();
}
}else{
echo "404: this is not accessible for you";
}
```